# Searching for items on the hardrive with a phrase.

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to set up a program on where there is something entered in will search the hard drive (c:\) for it in windows.  I got the code below entered but it takes the full path in the lookfor variable.  Im trying to figure out how can I set it up if I got a few letters matching to stop on them.  For example if I put Curr in the lookfor variable I would like it to find Current1.png, but instead I need to enter the full length items (Current1.png) to locate it.

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = 'Current1.png'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\'):
#print ('Searching', root)
if lookfor in files:
    print ('Found: %s' %join(root, lookfor))
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `os.walk()` is returning a list of files and you're searching for a string within that list of files

```
files = ['Current1.jpg', 'Current2.jpg', 'Current3.jpg']
```

If you search this list for 'Curr' it wont be found

```
>>> 'Curr' in files
False
>>> any(['Curr' in file for file in files])
True
```

Try change the code to

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = 'Curr'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:\\'):
    if any([lookfor in file for file in files]):
        print ('Found: %s' %join(root, lookfor))
        break
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (it has been a long day), `[file for file in files]` is just a copy of `files`. I guess you meant `any([lookfor in file for file in files])` or possibly `[file for file in files if lookfor in file]`.

Comment: AK that got it there, but now it found something ahead of what I was looking for.  Is there a way to set it up to step through until I find the location I am looking for.

Comment: You could change your list comprehension to a regular for loop and then do something like for file in files: if lookfor in file: print('Found %s': % join(root, file); break

Comment: Odly now it will not locate anything on my desktop but it will look inside folders on the desktop to locate things.